# Drag and drop is hidden when I drag out of div

Tags: jquery, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am using [`ng-draggable`](https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable) and [*malihu custom scroll bar*](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) and when I drag the `div` out I can't see it any more but it does drop into the other `div` correctly. I want to be able to **see** the `div` as I **drag** it to the other `div`.

I have created a Plunker with the issue:

https://plnkr.co/edit/GBnZCWORRc6lpTaGXd17?p=preview

Comment: I continue to do research on the issue and it seems like its an issue with the overflow: hidden property. I have tried to remove it but then the scroll no longer works. I have tried using z-index as well without any success.

Answer (score 0):

This is because, .mCustomScrollBox  and .mCustomScrollBox has overflow:hidden.

If you make those elements have overflow: visible, you will be able to see the movement, hence solving the issue at hand. But this will break the current behaviour, size of the box etc.

Comment: Yes, I agree the list of draggable divs continues outside of the containing div when overflow: hidden is applied. Is there any css that can keep the current functionality?

Comment: Not that I can think of off the top of my head. Not unless on drag, you make the dragged element not a part of that box any more. You could make it part of body temporarily and then add it where ever its dropped. I would suggest against above css fix unless you dont care about the long no scroll box.

Answer (score 0):

The library ng-draggable includes ng-drag-clone that you can use to clone the div that you are dragging. I have also included ng-drag-start to pass the data of the div being dragged.

```
ng-drag-clone:
  <div ng-drag-clone="" class="droppable-list">
 {{vm.clonedData.name}}
 </div>

ng-drag-start:
  <div class="droppable-list"  ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="d" 
  ng-drag-start="vm.onDragStart($data, $event)" 
  ng-drag-success="vm.onDatabaseDragCompleteSelection($data,$event)">
 {{d.name}}
 </div>

Controller:
  vm.onDragStart = function(data){
     vm.clonedData = data;
   }
```

Here is an updated Plunker: 
https://plnkr.co/edit/YTi0PK0VzvMC5OK1trRI?p=preview